# Surging of parallel motors

Tags: dc-motor

This question relates to an issue being encountered by a number of UK model railway enthusiasts so appears to be specific to the 4mm scale models themselves.

1. When two identical models, each with one supposedly identical 5-pole motors (equipped with flywheels), are coupled together (mechanically but not electrically) and operated around a model railway.
2. Except the models keep surging (or pulsing) by slowing down then regaining speed only to slow down, regain speed and so on.
3. Uncouple the models and run them a few inches apart on the same track and there is no surging; the surging only occurs when coupled.
4. Many other models with a much-higher current draw do not suffer from this surging.
5. There is a slight mismatch in speed between the supposedly identical 5-pole motors.
6. When running coupled, the two models appear to draw marginally more current.
7. A number of these models have been found to exhibit surging when coupled in pairs (or more).

The surging is cyclical around a layouts and occurs on a number of DC layouts (including coupling DCC-chipped models together running on 12v DC).
The surging is present with different controllers and does not appear to be track or power supply related.

What is causing the surging and how can it be eradicated?

Comment: You'll need to provide schematics or at least measure the voltage output from each motor with an oscilloscope when they operate normally vs in the problematic way. Otherwise it's all speculation - it sounds like conducted EMI but who can tell.

Comment: Thank you but sadly beyond my capabilities. Even if I had access to someone with an oscilloscope, the motors are contained within moving models. With look into conducted EMI.

Comment: So pry one open? You cannot often troubleshoot electronics by hmming and pondering while staring intently at the device, you have to get in there and measure the motor supply. Also, I wouldn't have a clue about how model trains are powered in general, but that would have to be investigated as well. Suppose the supply trips because of a current limit etc.

Comment: Sadly the motor mounted inside each are really difficult to access without causing damage. This is why my starting point is to explore less intrusive ideas and solutions. Whilst track voltage /controller amperage to the track's rails has be measured, trying to obtain readings from two moving models travelling along many yards of distance would also be be challenging.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that you'll be able to troubleshoot it otherwise. If you pry one open you can solder in the supply directly, then let it lie on its back while you measure with a scope. Although step #1 would be to measure the supply while you run them, I guess. Then you'll see if the supply itself surges.

Comment: The question was posted and answered. It does not belong to you anymore, but to the community. Do not vandalize it. Rolled back.

Comment: Much less worthy questions are allowed, I don’t agree with closing.

Answer (score 1):

Related answer here [Weird speed issues with brushed DC motors in parallel?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614419/weird-speed-issues-with-brushed-dc-motors-in-parallel)

I think one or both of the motors are operating close to stall. At this point track and brush resistance becomes significant, as well as power level. When one motor stalls,  the other loses power because of the voltage drop in the rails. You could experiment with resistance to balance this, maybe 0.5 to 1 ohm resistors inline to each motor, something to prevent either motor from pulling all the available power.